# HttpServletRequest parameters empty

Tags: javascript, java, post, servlets, tomcat9

I can't understand why in my servlet on my tomcat server, i can print out the parameters taken from a request but when check `user == null || user.isEmpty()` it gives me `true`.
This is the code for the servlet class.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/Login")
@MultipartConfig
public class login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Connection conn = null;
    
    public void init() {
        ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
        
        final String DB_URL = ctx.getInitParameter("dbUrl");
        final String USER = ctx.getInitParameter("dbUser");
        final String PASS = ctx.getInitParameter("dbPass");
        final String DRIVER = ctx.getInitParameter("dbDriver");
        
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
        
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String user = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        
        if(user == null || password == null || user.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) response.getWriter().write("missing fields");
    }
    
    public void destroy() {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    

}
```

I use javascript XMLHttpRequest to send the post request, and the formdata which contains the parameters.

To sends the form i use:

```
{
    document.getElementById("loginbutton").addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
        const formd = document.getElementById("login_form");
        
        makeCall("POST", "Login", formd, (request) => {
            if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
                console.log("Cioa");
            }
        }, null, false);
    });
}
```

as the caller of the function
and:

```
function makeCall(method, url, formElement, callBack , objectToSend , reset = true) {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        callBack(request);
    };

    request.open(method, url);

    if (formElement == null && objectToSend == null) {
        request.send();
    } else if(formElement != null){
        //Send the form
        request.send(new FormData(formElement));
    } else {
        //Send the object
        let toSend = JSON.stringify(objectToSend);
        request.send(toSend);
    }

    //If there is a form and reset is true -> reset the fields of the form
    if (formElement !== null && reset === true) {
        formElement.reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since user and password are usually sent in a header called "Authorization", how exactly do you send the request? Can you add this to the question please?

Comment: OK, my question was not precise enough - What I wanted to find out effectively was the content of the actual HTTP  call (without the form you use, it's hard to tell). Can you record one in your browser, anonymize it and add it to the question please? Including request headers and request body. Response is not of interest for now.